# How to throw own soap exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, .net-2.0

I want to throw our own soap exception, something like this,

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
  <soap:Fault>
   <faultcode>1001</faultcode>              
   <faultstring> This is asdasdaklj</faultstring>
   <detail />
  </soap:Fault>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

1001 is our own fault code, but don't know how to throw it ?

if try this,

```
 throw new SoapException("haha", SoapException.ServerFaultCode);
```

It throws    `<faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>`

Comment: Are you talking about WCF?

Comment: soap web services, asmx